# Is there an infinity of $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $2 {k \choose k/2} - 1$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, arithmetic, primality-test

my question is basically in the title.

Is there a way to answer it, or are there any theorems or conjectures regarding it?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: There is reason to suspect the answer is yes: as $\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ and the probability that a randomly selected integer $n$ is prime is roughly $1 / \ln n$, a naive estimate of the expected number of primes in the sequence $2 \binom{2n}{n} - 1$ is $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left[2 \binom{2n}{n} - 1\right]^{-1} \approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( n \ln 4 + \ln 2  - \frac{\ln \pi}{2} \ln n\right)^{-1} $$ which diverges as the harmonic series. (This argument can be generalized to any series that grows exponentially or slower.)

Comment: are there infinitely many binomial coefficients 1 more than a number not of form $2ab+a+b$ ?